# what distinguishes Rsync-type backups from other backups?

Tags: backup

[This link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backup_programs) classifies incremental backups into Rsync-type and other type:

> **Rsync-type backups**
>
> The main characteristic of this type of backups is that they maintain
>   a copy of the directory you want to keep a backup of, in a traditional
>   "mirror" fashion.
>
> Certain rsync-type packages also do snapshot backups by storing files
>   which describe how the contents of files and folders changed from the
>   last backup (so-called 'diffs'). Hence, they are inherently
>   incremental, but usually they do not have compression or encryption.
>   On the other hand, a working copy of everything is immediately
>   available, no decompression/decryption needed. A downside to
>   rsync-type programs is that they cannot be easily burned and restored
>   from a CD or DVD.
>
> **Other backups**
>
> Most other backup applications tend to create (big) archive files and
>   (of course) keep track of what's been archived. Creating .tar.bz2 or
>   .tar.gz archives has the advantage that you can extract the backups
>   with just tar/bzip2/gzip, so **you do not need to have the backup
>   program around**.

- what distinguishes Rsync-type backups from other backups?
- When restoring from "other backups", you do not need to have the backup
  program around but tar/bzip2/gzip.
  When restoring from "rsync-type backups", do we need to have the backup program around?

Comment: I think that "you do not need to have the backup program around" is ambiguous (or oxymoronic, since you *do* need to have tar etc. around).  It certainly doesn't contrast with `rsync`, where you don't need anything to restore because the mirror is already exactly the same as the original.

Answer (score 1):

- Rsync backups:

  - You do not need the program around if you used pure "mirroring" rsync. Just copy the files back (`cp -a`)
  - If you use regular incremental snapshots with hard-links as for example in [this popular setup](http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/) you will also be fine.
  - I think, however, than some rsync-based programs may have their own way of handling incremental backups, e.g. to support extra features like two-way sync.
- Other backups

  - In general you will need the program used to create them.
  - If you are lucky, the backup program may use a standard compression mechanism for full backups
  - But incremental backups will almost never be readable as-is.

Usually,

- rsync backups will be bigger
- hence they will also be longer to make the first time (but after that incremental backups should be competitive with archived ones)
- with rsync it is easier to e.g. restore just a subset of the backup (or just have a look a some files in the backup) without extracting anything.